# How to maintain Multiple concurrent user sessions in a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, restful-authentication

How to maintain multiple concurrent user sessions in a web application? I am using restful-authentication plugin for user authentication. when, I opened a new browser n log in as a different user, the session of the previous user is being killed. only one user is able to access my application at a time. Please help me out in solving this. 
I dont have much time. I hardly have two days to run into production. 
Any  suggestions are welcome!!

Thanks in advance !!
Nivedita

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because of your browser, not the Rails application. Try using a different browser and logging in.

Most browsers will only allow one session per domain without using an extension.